# MySQL with EntityFramework Core - Composite Foreign Key

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two tables `Project` and `ProjectMedia`. they are defined as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE `project` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LANG` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `DESCS` varchar(2048) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `SHORT_DESC` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`LANG`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`ID` and `LANG` are a composite primary key in the `Project` table.

`ProjectMedia` table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `project_media` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PATH` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TYPE` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IS_LOCAL_FILE` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PROJECT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LANG` char(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `PROJECT_MEDIA_PROJECT_PROJECT_ID_LANG_idx` (`PROJECT_ID`,`LANG`),
  CONSTRAINT `PROJECT_MEDIA_PROJECT_PROJECT_ID_LANG` FOREIGN KEY (`PROJECT_ID`, `LANG`) REFERENCES `project` (`ID`, `LANG`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have added two columns into ProjectMedia `PROJECT_ID` and `LANG` and I have created a composite foreign key for them to reference them into `project` table

but when I execute scaffold command as follow: I am getting this message

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=localhost;database=mydb;user=root;" "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" --output-dir "Persistence" --context "MyDbContext" --force
```

> Could not scaffold the foreign key 'mydb.project_media(PROJECT_ID)'. A
>   key for 'ID' was not found in the principal entity type 'Project'.
>   Could not scaffold the foreign key 'mydb.project_media(LANG)'. A key
>   for 'LANG' was not found in the principal entity type 'Project'.

What should I do?

Comment: Don't do it. Composite keys not worth having with EF. Make it unique key if you need to. With EF, best to normalize.

Comment: May be you **can't** - *"You can also use the Fluent API to configure multiple properties to be the key of an entity (known as a composite key). Composite keys **can only be configured using the Fluent API** - conventions will never setup a composite key and you can not use Data Annotations to configure one."* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys